# pd.Series - "Filename" KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble running a script for getting counts of predictions from csv files at a given directory. The format of the csv looks like this:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSATc.png)

and the code is the following:

```
    import os
    from glob import glob
    import pandas as pd

    def get_count(distribution, keyname):
    try:
        count = distribution[keyname]
    except KeyError:
        count = 0
    return count

    main_path = "K:\\...\\folder_name"

    folder_paths = glob("%s\\*" % main_path)
    data = []

    for path in folder_paths:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    results = pd.read_csv(path, error_bad_lines=False)results['Label'] = pd.Series(results['Filename'].str.split("\\").str[0])

    distribution = results.Predictions.value_counts()
    print(distribution)

    num_of_x = get_count(distribution, "x")
    num_of_y = get_count(distribution,"y")
    num_of_z = get_count(distribution,"z") 

    d = {"filename": file_name, "x": num_of_x, "y": num_of_y, "z": num_of_z}
    data.append(d)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(main_path,"summary_counts.csv"), index=False)
```

the output error is Keyerror: "Filename" reffering to the pd.Series function, anyone would know how to solve this?

I am using Python 3.7.3 and pandas 1.0.5 and I am a beginner in programming...

Many thanks in advance

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ".\save_counts.py", line 24, in <module>
results['Label'] = pd.Series(results['Filename'].str.split("\\").str[0])
File "K:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
", line 2800, in __getitem__
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "K:\...\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\
base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in           pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get
_loc
 File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in    pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get
 _loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.has
htable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.has
htable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Filename'
```

Comment: please add your full traceback

Comment: Can you print the names of the columns of `results` using `results.columns`? I suspect that there is a mistake in the name of the first column. Maybe it was opened in a notepad and stored in UTF-8, which may have added a disturbing character at the beginning of the file. That happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

in here:

```
for path in folder_paths:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    results = pd.read_csv(path, error_bad_lines=False)
    results['Label'] = pd.Series(results['Filename'].str.split("\\").str[0])
```

you are creating `pd.Series`, but those values exist only inside this `for` loop.

if after this loop you want to use `results` df in `distribution` you need to use `append()`

create empty df and append results in this df

```
final_results = pd.Dataframe()
for path in folder_paths:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
        results = pd.read_csv(path, error_bad_lines=False)
        results['Label'] = pd.Series(results['Filename'].str.split("\\").str[0])
        final_results = final_results.append(results)
#and from this point you can continue
```